# Are there risks or hidden costs of buying a CD from a bank I don't have an account with?

Tags: united-states, risk-management, certificate-of-deposit

I'm the treasurer for my church and we have $100K saved up to replace the roof of the sanctuary.  It'll be a year before we need the money, so I thought I should probably take the money out of savings and buy a CD with it.  The credit union with the church's checking and savings is offering 1 year CDs at 2.75%.

But there are other banks and bank-ish things out there, some in Austin, TX where I live and some online, offering 4% or more.

So my question is whether there are risks or hidden costs in taking the money to another bank, or any other considerations.   I don't want to open an checking account at a second bank, so a sub-question is whether that's typically a requirement (so that's the sort of "other consideration" I mean.)

It seems straightforward that I could just go online and buy one from any online bank and in a year earn $4000.  But I'm a little gun shy and would like to know if there are pitfalls to watch out for.

Comment: How much effort is it worth to earn $1,250 (the difference between $4000 and $2750), when opening a new business account at a different bank requires lots of people to agree?  IOW, probably best to KISS and open a 2.75% CD at the CU.

Comment: @RonJohn  Hassle is a consideration.  Being treasurer as a volunteer is a thankless job full of stupid hassles.  About once a month I recall that Judas was the treasurer for the Disciples.

Comment: Having said that, it would behoove you to start the ball rolling on opening a business account at an online bank, so that *next time* you can more easily open a CD at the online bank.  (I like Ally, but "only" have a bunch of individual accounts.)

Comment: The bank officer might say that they need all of the accounts. The investor could insist on the CD offering only but it's easier to work with Treasury Direct than with banks that want to market services.

Comment: Maybe just a nit, but if you buy a CD from a bank, you *do* have an account with them.

Comment: @JimMack  I've had a number of episodes in my life where a bank wouldn't do something because I didn't have a checking account there.  Once, the bank refused to cash a small paycheck drawn on their bank.  To get my money, I had to snail mail the check from Massachusetts to Nebraska and have it deposited in my bank.  It took 9 or 10 days to get my money.  I'd kiss a lawyer on the lips before I'd shake hands with a banker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One issue with a CD is that it is all or nothing. If you need it early there may be a penalty. If you only need 75% of it you have to cash it all in and then buy another CD or move the rest someplace else.

You group probably is interested in 100% security: so you want FDIC or NCUA coverage. for that money. Talk to the bank to see if there are any special rules because it isn't a personal account, it is a business account. Sometimes the best rates are for new customers, or new money.

You could also look into investing in US treasury bills. They have rates that are competitive with CD rates, and they are 100% guaranteed. Again make sure there aren't complications due to it being business funds.

Moving money outside the regular bank may require approval of your board, or multiple signatures, so check with your organization regarding the proper procedures.

Comment: Good point regarding personal vs business account, although there might be additional rules/exemptions for religious institutions/charities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The T-bill thing is a good idea for us, I think.  We already have a brokerage account which we hardly ever use (occasionally someone gives the church a gift of stock and we need a place for it to go.)

Answer (score 7):

One year treasuries and CDs are currently paying in the vicinity of of 4.75%.  Both are guaranteed, the former by the US goverment and the latter by FDIC insurance.  Ladder them if you think that you might need some of the money sooner - for example, 3, 6, 9, and 12 month maturities.

Treasuries require a brokerage account whereas CDs can be done in a brokerage account or in a money market account.

Some online banks offer no penalty CDs thought they tend to pay a lower rate.  For example, one that I'm aware of is for 11 months at 4.10% and you can withdraw the money any time before maturity without penalty.

Google for "best rates CDs and Treasuries"

Answer (score 3):

As long as the funds are insured under FDIC, it shouldn't matter which bank issues the CD.

You could consider opening a brokerage account and investing the funds in (a ladder of) brokered CDs depending on where you get the best rate.

This has the advantage that the funds would all be in the same investment account, without needing to open new accounts at each bank whose CD you want to invest in.